# How to compare and add the files in install shield

Tags: build, build-process, build-automation, installshield-2012

I tried to implement the automate build, for that i want compare the files and need to add new files in the project destination folder. how to do it this in grammatically.can you give me example code..or suggest any idea please....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but if you only want to dynamically link file folders to your component this is possible.

On the component you need your new files, use the "**link dynamical ...**" menu entry. There you can also define exclusion patterns.

If you now add files to the linked folder, you can build your installer and it will include the new files.